# DialogFragment UI still remains after dismiss

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, dialogfragment

I have a custom dialog fragment, the issue I am facing is that when the dismiss function is called, the dialog UI still remains on the screen even tho it's actually dismissed.
The `onDismiss` function is also called but the UI still sits on the parent fragment.

This is my dialog class

```
class IAPDialogFragment : DaggerDialogFragment() {
// Listener
var onSuccessfulIAP: (IAPDialogFragment.() -> Unit)? = null

override fun getTheme(): Int = R.style.DialogTheme

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? =
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.iap_dialog, container, false)

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    iap_dialog?.applyOutlineCornerRadius(30)

    setState(state, errorReason)
    action_button.setOnClickListener {
        dismiss()
    }
}

override fun onDismiss(dialog: DialogInterface) {
    super.onDismiss(dialog)
    if (this.state == State.SUCCESS) {
        onSuccessfulIAP?.invoke(this)
    }
}

fun setState(state: State, errorReason: IapException? = null) = apply {
    this.state = state
    this.errorReason = errorReason

    when (state) {
        State.LOADING -> {
            isCancelable = false
            action_button?.visibility = View.GONE
        }
        State.SUCCESS -> {
            isCancelable = true
            action_button?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            iap_dialog?.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.iap_card_success_background)
        }
        State.ERROR -> {
            isCancelable = true
            action_button?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the parent fragment:

```
class IAPFragment : DaggerFragment(){
private val dialog = IAPDialogFragment()

override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

    billingViewModel.state.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { state ->
        when (state) {
            State.OFFERS_LOADING -> showLoadingState()
            State.OFFERS_LOADING_FAILED -> showEmptyState()
            State.OFFERS_LOADED -> showOffers(billingViewModel.skuList)
            State.PURCHASING -> dialog.setState(LOADING)
            State.PURCHASING_SUCCESS -> dialog.setState(SUCCESS)
            State.PURCHASING_FAILED -> dialog.setState(ERROR, billingViewModel.errorReason)
            else -> showEmptyState()
        }
    }
}

private fun updateButton(position: Int) {
    subscribe_button.apply {
        setOnClickListener {
            dialog.setState(LOADING)
            dialog.show(childFragmentManager, LOADING.name)
        }
    }
}
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong? Is there any solution to refresh the UI state after the `DialogFragment` is dismissed?

Comment: in onDismiss function move the super command below the if statement and run. Hope that works.

Comment: Nope, no luck. What is very interesting is that after dismiss is called, the phone hangs and when I close the application, that frozen dialog UI will be set as the device's wallpaper!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many hours of investigation, I finally found the Animation in the Style was the issue. Apparently, DaggerDialogFragments have a compatibility issue with `android:windowAnimationStyle`.
The style I was using was:

```
<style name="DialogTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/DialogAnimation</item>
</style>

<style name="DialogAnimation">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/fragment_fade_enter</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/fragment_fade_exit</item>
</style>
```

I changed it to:

```
<style name="DialogTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/fragment_fade_enter</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/fragment_fade_exit</item>
</style>
```

And it magically solved the issue!

Comment: I also had this problem when upgrading to the latest fragment version to latest 1.4.0-alpha06

Comment: We don't use DaggerDialogFragments, just normal DialogFragments